# VIM: Jump outside of auto generated code in insert mode

Tags: vim

How do I jump outside of auto-generated code when I am in insert mode?

Use cases to describe what I mean

1. Launch Vim with *C Syntax* (`vim test.c`).
2. Enter Insert mode (Press **I**)
3. Type:
   `for (bla) {`
4. Hit enter
5. It expands into.

`for (bla) {
   (CURSOR)
}`

6. Type body of a loop
7. **How do I jump my cursor to the outside of the loop** without tiresome sequence of: *Esc -> few J's -> $ -> I*

So that it would be:

```
for(bla) {
  body
}(CURSOR)
```

P.S. Ideally - general solution, for any auto-generated code that happens in Insert mode.

Comment: A general solution could be to use a snippet plugin: UltiSnips, or neosnippet. With both, you can use or define snippets similar to what you describe, with more than one jump points (even having default text placeholders); the last jump point can be "an exit point" - i.e. the final cursor position. See for example: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-ultisnips/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try a mapping, for example `F6`:

```
inoremap <f6> <esc>]MA
```

then you can just press `<F6>` to move your cursor to the desired position, still staying in Insert mode.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain the meaning of `]` and `M`?

Comment: Basically the same: `<esc>]}A`.